# ember-cli extend assert with custom assertion helpers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, qunit, ember-qunit

In the latest ember-cli, in the unit tests the `test` function expect as last parameter a function which would have the `assert` object as first parameter.

I was wondering how can I extend this object to add my own custom assertion helpers?

For example I want to add a `controlDisabled` helper that would return true if the control is disabled, and false otherwise. So somewhere (but not in each test files) I want to extend that `assert` object given as paramter like so:

```
assert.controlDisabled = function(selector, message) {
  return this.ok(findWithAssert(selector).attr('disabled'), message);
};
```

Where should I define this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assert` object is a singleton instance which you can gain access with `QUnit.assert`. So the following should work

```
import QUnit from 'qunit';

QUnit.assert.controlDisabled = function(selector, message) {
  return this.ok(findWithAssert(selector).attr('disabled'), message);
};
```